# float doesn't register

Tags: c#

Example:

```
Output when debugging: bVar= 0.0
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are dividing integers, not floats.

Use `float bVarianza = (499f/ 500f);` instead.

Your expression is evaluated as

`float x = (float) (int / int)`.

After your integers have been divided (which results in 0 because integers don't have a fractal part) the result is stored in your variable of type float, which adds the .0 fractal part.

Answer (score 2):

You divide an `int` by an `int`, so the answer is truncated to an `int`.  That is, the expression `499/500` is evaluated to `0`.  Then you store `0` in a `float`, so it becomes `0.0`.

If instead you say `499F / 500`, then the expression itself will be a `float`, and you'll get a fractional result.

Answer (score 0):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691373%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) :

> The division rounds the result towards zero, and the absolute value of
>   the result is the largest possible integer that is less than the
>   absolute value of the quotient of the two operands. The result is zero
>   or positive when the two operands have the same sign and zero or
>   negative when the two operands have opposite signs.

So if you want to get a `float` as result, you should cast types like

```
float bVarianza = (float)499 / (float)500;
```

in the case when one of operands is Real number, you can only cast the result:

```
float bVarianza = (float)(499/500.0);
```