# Divide an integer by 100 and get value till two decimal points?

Tags: c#, rounding

I have `String` amount in a `TextBox`, which I want to divide by 100.

The value should round off to two decimal places.
I tried and I am not getting a proper value.

Here is what I tried:

```
6766/100 = 67.66
47/100 = .47
98/100 = .98
```

Comment: It's doing an `int` calculation because both operands are ints. Try changing one of the numbers to a double by adding ".0", e.g. `6766/100.0`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22521867/float-doesnt-register-under-1/22521940#22521940

Comment: @MatthewWatson You should add a `d` for double, i.e. `0d`.

Comment: @aevitas Why? Adding `.0` makes it a double too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's wrong with this division?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/704702/whats-wrong-with-this-division)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you round a number to two decimal places in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257005/how-do-you-round-a-number-to-two-decimal-places-in-c)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [Math.Round](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75ks3aby.aspx). This example should get you going

```
string txtText = "78907";

double inputValue;

if (double.TryParse(txtText, out inputValue))
   double result = Math.Round(inputValue / 100, 2);
```

**Output:**
    789.07

Answer (score 4):

Use `Math.Round`, but one of both need to be a decimal type to avoid integer division:

```
double result = Math.Round(6766d / 100, 2);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `Math.Round`. It has a parameter called precision.

Example:

```
Math.Round(1.23456, 2) -> 1.23
```

Answer (score 0):

Math.round will do.

```
Math.Round(1.23456, 2);
```

It will round input at 2 decimals